# Is there any way to create users with roles assigned in keycloak using node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

i was trying a code to upload all users to keycloak user list and it works well. i used an excel file to read then push each row into keycloak field but i was thinking to add roles to each user at the same time. when i try out this code it says role field does not exist in user and gives me error

this is my code

**Read From Excel and store in an array**

```
let path = 'http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/msportal';
let _userTobeCreated = ReadFromExcel('./uploads/employees-roles.xlsx');

function ReadFromExcel(filename) {
    let userTobeCreated = []

    xlsxFile(filename).then((rows) => {
        rows.forEach(row => {
            let userObject = {
                username: row[0],
                lastName: row[1],
                firstName: row[2],
                email: row[3],
                roles: row[4].split(',')

            }
            userTobeCreated.push(userObject);

        });
    })
    return userTobeCreated;

}
```

**create function**

```
function CreateKCBulkUser(user) {
  let urlCreateUser = `${path}/users`;
  return axios({

    method: 'post',
    url: urlCreateUser,
    data: JSON.stringify(user),
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${kc_accessToken}`
    }

  })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log("User created!!");
      _userlists = response.data;

    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

**Calling Function**

```
   _usersToBeCreated.forEach((v)=>{
        CreateKCBulkUser(v);
      })
```

excel file

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Role is not a part of `user` entity. First you must create `role` entity and then you need to create `role-mapping`. See [API doc](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/11.0/rest-api/index.html).

BTW: `role` is vague definition, because Keycloak has real roles/client roles + I would use [keycloak-nodejs-admin-client](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-nodejs-admin-client) instead of plain axios requests.